# Is there a way to get Visual Studio code to recognize the .upc file format?

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-format, upc

Is there a way to get Visual Studio code to recognize the .upc file format? .UPC is "Unified Parallel C"

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview

> ### Changing the language for the selected file
>
> In VS Code, we default the language support for a file based on its filename extension. However, at times you may wish to change language modes, to do this click on the language indicator - which is located on the right hand of the Status Bar. This will bring up the **Select Language Mode** drop-down where you can select another language for the current file.
>
> **Tip**: You can get the same drop-down by running the Change Language Mode command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>).